# How do I make it so that the all users page is not a white screen?

Tags: wp-admin, users

I tried to up the amount of users displayed on the screen, and then after clicking 'Apply', the Users page stays white for me, and only the user page. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "Undo what you did", but you did not explain what you did so I am assuming that what you did was change the "Screen Option" value on the `wp-admin/users.php` page. If that is the case, you need to get into the database via PhpMyAdmin or some other tool and change the `users_per_page` value for your user.

You can also add the following to your theme's `functions.php`, load a page, and then remove it.

```
// change '1' to your user ID
// 20 is the default value so it should set things back to normal
update_user_meta(1,'users_per_page',20);
```